# Moving Collections from TFS 2015 to TFS 2018

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I am doing an upgrade from TFS 2015 to TFS 2018.
I moved a collection from my TFS 2015 to my TFS 2018 as refered in the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/admin/move-project-collection

The process was successfully done according with TFS 2018 Administration Console after I attached it.

After this I compared both collections (from TFS 2015 and 2018).
I could watch that the migration was not entirely done. In TFS 2018 I was missing this:

- In my original Collection I had 3 projects. THe projects are still in there, however Project P1 used to have 6 members (4 users and 2 groups). Now it only has 4 users. The groups are missing. Any idea why?
- In Project P1, In TFS 2015 I had a Visual Studio definition build. Now, In TFS 2018 I could see that the "Publish Build Artifact" is now deprecated.
- In this build options I noticed in my "Multipiers" field I have this message "This setting is required". In TFS 2015 I could leave this field empty and I wouldn't get this message.

At the moment I haven't noticed any more changes, but I am worried about this.
I have more collection to migrate from TFS 2015 to TFS 2018-
How should I address this migrate process?

Comment: Some build tasks and options have changed and need to be resolved manually. These build definitions will have a red  in the ui to signal a human must look at it. In the past we've scripted some changes and used the rest api to bulk update certain issues.

Comment: Multipliers is required in case parallel execution is checked. You can probably safely turn it off.

Comment: My colleague has shared some of the scripts we use with Azure Devops migrations to solve similar issues, they may be of help to you https://github.com/JasperGilhuis/AzureDevOpsMigration

Comment: Thanks.I'll check them- By the way, Is there a way to migrate each collection at the time, when I install and upgrade TFS 2018 in a new machine? When I run the Server Configuration Wizard I didn't notice any option to choose which collection to move. Instead all the collections have been moved.

Comment: You can install an "empty" TFS 2018 server and then use a Detach+Attach migration, basically detaching a collection from TFS 2015, backing up the database, restoring it on the 2018 server and then attaching it. This is a riskier approach and it takes much longer. If you have multiple collections it may limit the impact on your teams and that can be a trade-off.

Comment: See the guidance here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/admin/move-project-collection

Comment: The reccomended upgrade approach is to take **all** collections at once and perform an in-place upgrade. Either on the existing systems or by setting up a new system and performing the "Upgrade" installation as explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/upgrade/get-started

Comment: Thanks. I had already seen that documentation. But how can I install an empty TFS ? I don't recall nothing on the installation options that points me in that direction?

Comment: Just the installer and point it to a SQL server instance. It will create new databases to work from.

Comment: So what you are saying is that when I run the installer I should choose choose the option "This is a new team foundation deployment (...TFS will create new databases)"?  The thing is, I'd like to install TFS 2018 in a new machine and point it to my old database.

Comment: Depending on what you want, yes. If you want to migrate collections one at a time, you'd use the 'new install' + detach & attach. If you want to migrate them all at once you use the upgrade scenario. You can use a database prefix to have the new tfs install run on the same SQL server instance.

Comment: So, do you think that by doing that procedure (use a new database and importing collections one by one) will I loose anything from my old TFS 2015? (TFS 2015 is installed in a different machine).

Comment: Ok. Why 3.1? :) I have tried to find documentation about it but I still couldn't find anything about this. I just wanted to know to show it to some colleagues :)

Comment: Never mind, I had TFS 2013 update 4 in mind, you can find the detach issues in the release notes for that version: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2994375/description-of-visual-studio-2013-update-4

Comment: I'll read that. Thanks.